# cannot assign value of type [Any object] to [uiviewcontroller]?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, ios9

i am trying to make uitabbar based on my json response array.

this is my json response

```
tabs =     (
        {

    id = 0;
    name = Home;

},
        {

    id = 1;
    name = Winkel;

},
        {

    id = 2;
    name = Zoeken;

}
```

);
 })

now this is my code which i tried::

```
func loadTabbarsWithArray(tabs: [AnyObject]) {
    if self.tabBarController == nil {
        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

    }
    self.tabBarController!.viewControllers = [AnyObject]()
    var viewControllers: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject](arrayLiteral: 0)
    for record: [NSObject : AnyObject] in tabs {
        var viewController: UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "CustomViewController", bundle: nil)
        viewController.title = record["name"]
        viewController.tabBarItem.title = record["name"]
        viewControllers.append(viewController)
    }
    self.tabBarController!.viewControllers = viewControllers as? [UIViewController]
}
```

this is image which indicate errors[image]

Comment: You should use `[UIViewController]` instead of `[AnyObject]`, this should solve your problem. Why are you using an array of `AnyObject` in the first place?

Comment: okk got it but what about second error? @Cristik

Comment: What about the second error? It should dissappear if you follow my suggestion

Comment: i am using anyobject because i want to make tab bar based on my json response array.@Cristik

Comment: There's no direct relation between your `json` and the `tabBarController`. You can have any json response, as long as you satisfy the tab bar controller by providing it what it expects - i.e. an array of view controllers.

Comment: @AnkitThakur please then flag the question as duplicate, if it is

Answer (score 2):

In your code you try to set the `viewControllers` property of your `UITabBarViewController` with an `[AnyObject]` object. According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/viewControllers), this property must be an `[UIViewController]?`.

```
func loadTabbarsWithArray(tabs: [AnyObject]) -> Int {

    guard let tabsOk = tabs as? [[String : String]] else {
        return -1
    }

    if self.tabBarController == nil {
        self.tabBarController = UITabBarController()

    }
    self.tabBarController!.viewControllers = nil
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController] = []
    for record: [String : String] in tabsOk {
        var viewController: UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "CustomViewController", bundle: nil)
        viewController.title = record["name"]
        viewController.tabBarItem.title = record["name"]
        viewControllers.append(viewController)
    }
    self.tabBarController!.viewControllers = viewControllers
    return viewControllers.count
}
```

Comment: thanx @michael while using your code how can i call this function. because when i call it like loadTabbarsWithArray(arr) its showing me error Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray' to expected argument type '[[String : String]].

Comment: this is my array content arr =     (
        {

    id = 0;
    name = Home;

},
        {

    id = 1;
    name = Winkel;

},
        {

    id = 2;
    name = Zoeken;

}
)

Comment: I've edited my answer to accept an `[AnyObject]` argument. The function now returns the number of view controllers loaded or -1 if the array wasn't properly formatted.

Comment: you are not getting my question with this code its reurn -1. but i have a array with this format  arr = ( { id = 0; name = Home; }, { id = 1; name = Winkel; }, { id = 2; name = Zoeken; } ) so how can i create controller with this array@Michael

Comment: Are the fields of you json array properly parsed or do you have an array or string ? What do you get if you replace temporarily the code of this function by `guard let tabsOk = tabs as? [[String : AnyObject]] else {
        return -1
    }
return 0 `

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
func loadTabbarsWithArray(let tabs:[[String: Any]]){

        if (self.tabBarController == nil) {
            self.tabBarController = UITabBarController();
        }
        tabBarController!.viewControllers = [UIViewController]();

        var viewControllers = [UIViewController]();
        for  record:[String: Any] in tabs {
            let viewController:UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "CustomViewController", bundle: nil);
            viewController.title = record["name"] as? String;
            viewController.tabBarItem.title = record["name"]as? String;
            viewControllers.append(viewController);
        }
        tabBarController!.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post.